# What is the correct syntax to test an array using CollectionAssert in VS 2013?

Tags: c#, arrays, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

Just learning how to conduct unit tests in c# using Visual Studio 2013. I have created a test which assigns specific floating numbers to an array but not sure how to test. I am attempting to use the `CollectionAssert` class but cannot get the syntax right.

Code snippet:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ArrayTest()
{
        float[] grades;
        grades = new float[2];

        grades[0] = 91f;
        grades[1] = 89.1f;

        foreach (float grade in grades)
            Console.WriteLine(grade);
}
```

I just want to test whether or not the grades will be printed to console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Grant asked, what are you trying to test?
Just testing simple values, this works as expected

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CheckFloats()
    {
        float[] array1 = new float[] { 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f };
        float[] array2 = new float[] { 4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f };

        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(array1, GenerateFloats());
    }

    private float[] GenerateFloats()
    {
        return new float[] { 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f };
    }
```

It passes as written.  It fails if swap *array2* for *array1* in the AreEqual call.